# Extracting policy data into csv file

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I want to take data from the the gx model and save it into csv file. There are following challenge i am facing -

1. How to store gxmodel file into a object.
2. after storing the object, what are the way to store it in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

If my understanding is correct, U have an xml input and u need to store the data into a POJO class(object).

1. If that is the requirement, u need to parse the xml -> pick each value and map it to the pojo.
2. If its a gx model, u might have the schema (XSD) also, in that case GW auto generates(in ver 9) and u can directly access the xml content through the instance created by GW for the particular GX model. The rest is mapping which wont be a great deal.

Question 2:

1. For `ListIterator` we can directly export the content to csv (or any oth) format. You can refer --`Batch History Export`-- functionality for the same.
2. Many jars are available for the same also.
3. CSV means comma separated values. U can even create a file with the same logic and save it with `.csv` extension.

Hope this makes sense. :)